# Pretrained handwritten OCR model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, ocr

I've been looking around for pretrained models dedicated to handwritten OCR. So far I've found very little. Could you please share, if you know any?
I find `tesseract` hard to parse anything that isn't *arial* and perfectly captured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discover open-source deep learning code and pretrained models at [Model Zoo](https://modelzoo.co/)

These are pre-trained sources available in the Github.

1. [Handwritten Text Recognition with TensorFlow](https://github.com/githubharald/SimpleHTR)

   [More](https://towardsdatascience.com/faq-build-a-handwritten-text-recognition-system-using-tensorflow-27648fb18519)
2. [Handwriting OCR](https://github.com/Breta01/handwriting-ocr)
3. [Handwritten Text Recognition (OCR) with MXNet Gluon](https://github.com/awslabs/handwritten-text-recognition-for-apache-mxnet)

Some Helpful Resources:

1. [Handwriting recognition and language modeling with MXNet Gluon](https://medium.com/apache-mxnet/handwriting-ocr-handwriting-recognition-and-language-modeling-with-mxnet-gluon-4c7165788c67)
2. [Handwriting OCR: Line segmentation with Gluon](https://medium.com/apache-mxnet/handwriting-ocr-line-segmentation-with-gluon-7af419f3a3d8)